# I am trying to build a scroll down feature in chatbot screen but it does not work and other issues

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I am trying to build a simple chatbot and I want the chat screen to scroll down when new messages arrive. I tried somewhat everything but wont work. Here is my HTML code:

```html
<div id="conv" class="chat-body">

  <div class="chat-bubble you">Hallo, wie kann ich Ihnen helfen?</div>
  <div id="custo"></div>

  <!-- <div id="custo"> <span id = "heart"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true" ></i> </span> </div> -->
  <div id="berbot"></div>
  <div id="bouncers" class="chat-bubble you">
  </div>

</div>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```js
function pushChat() {

  // if there is text to be sent...
  var wisdomText = document.getElementById('wisdom');
  if (wisdomText && wisdomText.value && wisdomText.value.trim().length > 0) {

    // disable input to show we're sending it
    var wisdom = wisdomText.value.trim();
    wisdomText.value = '...';
    wisdomText.locked = true;

    // send it to the Lex runtime
    var params = {
      botAlias: '$LATEST',
      botName: 'Chatbotwebpage',
      inputText: wisdom,
      userId: lexUserId,
      sessionAttributes: sessionAttributes
    };
    showRequest(wisdom);
    lexruntime.postText(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
        showError('Error:  ' + err.message + ' (see console for details)')
      }
      if (data) {
        // capture the sessionAttributes for the next cycle
        sessionAttributes = data.sessionAttributes;
        // show response and/or error/dialog status
        showResponse(data);
      }
      // re-enable input
      wisdomText.value = '';
      wisdomText.locked = false;
    });
  }
  // we always cancel form submission
  return false;
}

function showRequest(daText) {
  var firstconversationDiv = document.getElementById('custo');
  var requestPara = document.createElement("P");
  requestPara.className = 'chat-bubble you';
  requestPara.appendChild(document.createTextNode(daText));
  firstconversationDiv.appendChild(requestPara);
  firstconversationDiv.scrollTop = firstconversationDiv.scrollHeight;

}

function showError(daText) {

  var conversationDiv = document.getElementById('berbot');
  var errorPara = document.createElement("P");
  errorPara.className = 'lexError';
  errorPara.appendChild(document.createTextNode(daText));
  conversationDiv.appendChild(errorPara);
  conversationDiv.scrollTop = conversationDiv.scrollHeight;
}

function showResponse(lexResponse) {

  var conversationDiv = document.getElementById('custo');
  var responsePara = document.createElement("P");
  responsePara.className = 'chat-bubble me';
  if (lexResponse.message) {
    responsePara.appendChild(document.createTextNode(lexResponse.message));
    responsePara.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  }

  // if (lexResponse.dialogState === 'ReadyForFulfillment') {
  //     responsePara.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
  //         dati));
  //     // TODO:  show slot values
  // } else {
  //     responsePara.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
  //         dati));
  // }
  conversationDiv.appendChild(responsePara);
  conversationDiv.scrollTop = conversationDiv.scrollHeight;

}
```

CSS code:

```css
.chat-screen .chat-body {
    padding: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 350px;
    min-height: 382px;
    max-height: 382px;
    background: white;
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow: scroll;
    scroll-behavior: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.chat-screen .chat-body .chat-bubble.you {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #7292d4, #5681d7, #336cdc, #1156e1, #034cdd);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 15px 15px 15px;
  float: left;
  align-self: flex-start;
  display: table;
  border-color: 2px #030303;
}

.chat-screen .chat-body .chat-bubble.me {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #FFFFFF, #FFFFFF, #FFFFFF, #FFFFFF, #FFFFFF);
  color: black;
  border-radius: 15px 0px 15px 15px;
  float: right;
  align-self: right;
  display: table;
}
```

The other issues I have:

1. chat messages will only align left or right after the second or third message arrives.
2. I am trying to add an instagram heart feature as a like button. I have copy pasted the code from this link: https://codepen.io/bneupane/pen/KMKzZZ

and added the html code into my div like this:

```html
<div id="custo"> <span id = "heart"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true" ></i> </span> </div>
```

but when I do this, the javascript does not create the i class heart inside the div automatically and I do not know how to do it right.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried ? Have you tried to set `conversationDiv.scrollTop = conversationDiv.scrollHeight - conversationDiv.clientHeight` ?

Comment: yes I have tried this!

Comment: And have you tried to console.log conversationDiv to check if it is well defined ? Do you have any error message in the console ? What have you tried

Comment: Yes there is no output regarding the scroll behavior.

Comment: You should detail a little bit more in your post what you have tried and what outpouts you have in the console in your tries.

Comment: There is absolutely no output about the scroll behavior. No errors, nothing. It just does not scroll. I have tried it also in different browsers.

Comment: I have made some edits to CSS code, still not workin. Tried with jquery still not working.